# What's the most robust and readable way of ensuring objects conform to a interface/protocol in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, interface, protocols

I'm trying code to an interface (or a protocol in Objective C terminology), not an implementation.

It's critical that we check objects conform to protocol before calling methods on them to prevent crashes.

**Three Ways**

1. In compiler
2. At runtime
3. Both

**Best Solution... Surely Number 1?**

I thought the best way would be in the compiler:

- Warnings ahoy if you screw up
- Eliminates conformsToProtocol:/respondsToSelector: boilerplate
- At runtime it's too late if you made a mistake - the best you can do is not execute the code/show an error

But I see a lot of code that's doing it at runtime. Why?

Is it a readability issue - needing `id <Protocol>` everywhere?

**My Question**

What's the most robust and readable way of ensuring objects conform to a interface/protocol?

**Code**

**1. Checking In Compiler**

```
@interface ReportController : NSObject {
    id <ReportGenerator> generator;
    id <ReportSender> sender;
    id report;
}

@implementation ReportController

-(id)initWithReportGenerator:(id <ReportGenerator>)generator_
                reportSender:(id <ReportSender>)sender_ {
    // Usual init stuff
    generator = generator_;
    sender = sender_;
    return self;
}

-(void)generateAndSend {
    report = [generator generate];
    [sender sendReport:report];
}

@end
```

**2. Checking At Runtime**

```
@interface ReportController : NSObject {
    id generator;
    id sender;
    id report;
}

@implementation ReportController

-(id)initWithReportGenerator:(id)generator_
                reportSender:(id)sender_ {
    // Usual init stuff
    generator = generator_;
    sender = sender_;
    return self;
}

-(void)generateAndSend {
    if ([generator conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ReportGenerator)] &&
        [sender conformsToProtocol:@protocol(ReportSender)]) {
        report = [generator generate];
        [sender sendReport:report];
    } else {
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Objects didn't respond to protocols..."];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use both. Consider e.g.:

```
@protocol Proto
- (void)someFunction;
@end

@interface C : NSObject
- (void)proto:(id<Proto>)p;
@end

// ...
NSString *s = @"moo";
id i = s;

C *c = [[C alloc] init];
[c proto:s]; // warns
[c proto:i]; // doesn't warn
```

Objective-C and Cocoa are too dynamic to generally check such things at compile time (`NSProxy` standins, classes dynamically adding methods and protocols, ...).
It is nice to catch as many of such errors at compile-time as possible, but that alone is not sufficient.

Comment: Excellent point. Can't believe I didn't see this earlier. All this protocol checking plus type checking makes complete sense now. Thanks! Just one more question - how would you handle the protocol not conforming - just not do anything? Throw an exception? Or return an error?

Comment: @John: Tough question, that really depends on the context.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you don't use plain `id` as the type, the compiler will at least warn you if you make a mistake at compile time. So you should be fine with your code example #1.

Of course, sometimes you might be forced to work with an `id` object that you get from a subsystem that is not under your control. In such cases you can cast the object back to the type you *think* it has (e.g. `id <ReportGenerator>`), but you are usually better off if you perform a runtime check first. Better be safe than sorry...

On a final note: If your protocol has optional parts (declared with the `@optional` keyword), then for those parts you will obviously be able to do runtime checks only. The `@required` keyword mentioned by apurv is necessary only if you want to be explicit in your protocol declaration (a protocol's parts are required by default), or if you mix optional and required parts.

Answer (score 0):

You should create methods with @required type in protocol.
So whatever class wants to take a contract with this protocol, will must have to implement those methods.
It will definitely make sure that the required methods are available at compile time only.

Comment: `@required` is the default and it will not generally ensure the presence of methods at compile time.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche: Can you explain what you mean by "will not generally ensure the presence of methods at compile time"? I was under the impression that as long as you work with explicit types and do not use plain `id`, the compiler will check that a class conforms to a protocol.

Comment: @herzbube: One thing is that it's just a type check and in the presence of such non-strict conversions like `id` to basically anything it's no help. Then you can't generally ensure the presence of methods at compile time - the implementation may be in dynamically loaded code (shared libraries etc.), different project/process (e.g. Distributed Objects) or you may have classes being built at runtime.